# changing the style of span from javascript

Tags: javascript, css

i have a span tag in javascript file like that

```
<input type="text" id="name" onblur="submitFormEmail()"/>
<span class="error">This is an error</span>
```

and here is its style in the css

```
.form_wrapper span.error{
visibility:hidden;
color:red;
font-size:11px;
font-style:italic;
display:block;
margin:4px 30px;
}
```

how can i change the visibility of the span when calling the function submitFormEmail()??

```
function submitFormEmail(){

}
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('.error').style.visibility = 'visible'`

Answer (score 0):

Just

```
document.getElementsByClassName(".error")[0].style.visibility="visible";
```

Comment: with the caveat that this will affect *all* elements with the class `error` (not just the one span)

Answer (score 0):

To call it in your function you can do the following:

`function submitFormEmail(){
       document.querySelector('.error').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there has many `input` elements, so the function should find out which node be match.

```js
function submitFormEmail(obj) {
  var nextSpan = obj.nextSibling;
  while(nextSpan.nodeType != 1){
    nextSpan = nextSpan.nextSibling;
  }
  nextSpan.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

```css
.error {
  visibility: hidden;
  color: red;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-style: italic;
  display: block;
  margin: 4px 30px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name" onblur="submitFormEmail(this)" /> <span class="error">This is an error</span> <br/>
<input type="text" id="name1" onblur="submitFormEmail(this)" /> <span class="error">This is an error</span> <br/>
<input type="text" id="name2" onblur="submitFormEmail(this)" /> <span class="error">This is an error</span>
```